# flask_cors installed correctly and highlighted in vs code however getting an error

Tags: python, flask, visual-studio-code, import, flask-cors

Used the command pip install flask-cors and successfully installed it in vscode[image]

however when trying to run the command python app.py I am presented with the error:

[image]

Comment: In the command prompt, try `pip freeze` to see if `flask_cors` is installed in the same environment.

Comment: Run `pip show flask_cors` in current terminal, can you see detailed information like version and installation location? if not, it means there's no `flask_cors` in `venv`, install it.

Answer (score -1):

Some ideas for troubleshooting (too long for a comment):

1. Run `python` from the command line, then import cors. Does it work on the default Python installation?
2. Check that VS Code is using the right Python installation. On Windows, the default installation (sometimes installed through the Windows Store) may be selected in favor of your manual installs through the website.
3. Are you using a virtual environment (conda, venv, etc.)? If so, make sure that VS Code has picked it up correctly, and that you've installed cors for the specific environment.